# Get document scores within Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

we query multiple indices but with different field names and merge the result into a global search. To add pagination, I want to use the scores by sorting the results by score and calculate the page myself.

My question is now: How to I get the score for each document? I saw that I can sort by score but not how the get the actual score value.

Any help is apreciated!

P.S. I'm using an Elasticsearch backend and hibernate search 6.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the documentation: [`score` projection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-score).

```
List<Float> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .select( f -> f.score() )
        .where( f -> f.match().field( "title" )
                .matching( "robot dawn" ) )
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

And if you want the entity *and* the score, use both the `score` projection and the [`entity` projection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-entity), and combine them with a [`composite` projection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-composite).

```
List<MyPair<Book, Float>> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .select( f -> f.composite( 
                MyPair::new, 
                f.entity(), 
                f.score() 
        ) )
        .where( f -> f.matchAll() )
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

Note that Hibernate Search 6.2 (still in development) will introduce a slightly more explicit syntax:

```
List<MyPair<Book, Float>> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .select( f -> f.composite()
                .from( f.entity(), f.score() )
                .as( MyPair::new ) )
        .where( f -> f.matchAll() )
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

Comment: Thank you yrodiere, that answers my question perfectly. Can I somehow add a static value to f.composite? I see that I can reference fields, the entity, the score etc.

Comment: You mean a constant? Yes, but only with Hibernate Search 6.2 (still in Alpha): https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-constant